# Instabot Posts Images but Not Captions

Tags: python, instagram

I'm building a bot that fetches images from the Unsplash API, and then reposts them on Instagram. Each image comes with a caption that is generated using the function getQuote(). The issue I am facing is that the captions do not get uploaded. I have tried isolating the problem by putting simple string instead of getting the data from a function, but to no avail, as Instabot does not post the caption on Instagram.
Below is the upload function:

```
def upload(path): 
bot.upload_photo(path, caption="Follow for more!")
toast.show_toast("Notification",str(num)+" images are uploaded",duration=300,threaded=True)
print(str(num)+" images are uploaded")
print("----------------------------------")
try:
    os.remove(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), path+""))
except:
    os.remove(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), path+".REMOVE_ME"))
```

The last 4 lines delete the already uploaded images.
In an ideal scenario the bot.upload would have a `caption=getQuote()`
Yesterday, while testing how fast the bot can upload(the captions worked back then), Instagram cut my access, but today I can still upload images, but without captions. Going on Instagram and manually changing captions is possible, so I doubt some server-side ban. If I just create a print statement calling the function getQuote - I get an adequate response, which means that the quotes are successfully loaded from the quotes.json file.

Below is my entire code:

```
    from instabot import Bot 
    from skimage.io import imread_collection
    from glob import glob
    from win10toast import ToastNotifier
    import random
    import json
    import os
    import urllib.request
    import time
    import requests
    import smtplib
    import smtplib
    from tkinter import *
    from fake_useragent import UserAgent
    ua = UserAgent()
    
    num=0
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Photos Uploaded")
    window.iconbitmap("Instagram/Instagram.ico")
    lbl = Label(window, text=num, font=("Arial Bold", 100))
    lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
    window.update()
    #This functions checks if the site is up
    def url_ok(url):
        r = requests.head(url)
        return r.status_code == 200
    
    #Below functions sends emails 
    def sendMessage(Num):
        gmail_user = ''
        gmail_password = ''
        sent_from = gmail_user
        to = ['']
        subject = 'Upload Count'
        body = "Upload Count"
        email_text = Num
        try:
            server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
            server.ehlo()
            server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
            server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
            server.close()
        except:
            print("Could not send a push-notification!")
    
    with open("Instagram/NumberOfImagesUploaded.txt", "r") as f:
       num = int(float(f.read()))
    #This functions loads the number of already uploaded images from a file
    def ChangeNum(n):
        num=n
        with open("Instagram/NumberOfImagesUploaded.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write(str(int(n)))
    
    links=[]
    r=''
    with open(os.path.abspath("Instagram/Data/links.txt"), 'r') as filehandle:
        for line in filehandle:
            currentPlace = line[:-1]
            links.append(currentPlace)
    print("Started at: " +time.ctime()+" with a list of "+str(len(links))+" links.")
#This functions gets images from the API    
def GetImage():
        r = requests.get('https://source.unsplash.com/featured/3840x2160')
        while r.url == "https://images.unsplash.com/source-404?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=800&q=60&w=1200":
            print("API requests are over capita! Waiting one hour. Continuing at "+str(time.ctime(time.time() + 3600)+"..."))
            time.sleep(3600)
            print("Trying again... "+time.ctime())
            r = requests.get('https://source.unsplash.com/featured/3840x2160')
        try:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(str(r.url), os.path.abspath("Instagram/media")+"\\"+str(random.randrange(1,10000))+".jpg")
        except:
            print("API requests are over capita! Waiting in 10 hours. Continuing at "+str(time.ctime(time.time() + 36000)+"..."))
            time.sleep(36000)
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(str(r.url), os.path.abspath("Instagram/media")+"\\"+str(random.randrange(1,10000))+".jpg")
        while r.url in links:
            r = requests.get('https://source.unsplash.com/featured/3840x2160')
       
        links.append(r.url)
        with open(os.path.abspath("Instagram/Data/links.txt"), 'w') as filehandle:
            for listitem in links:
                filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)
    GetImage()
    print("Backup image loaded at: " +time.ctime())
    toast = ToastNotifier()
    col_dir =os.path.abspath("Instagram/media")+"\\"+("*.jpg")
    col = glob(col_dir)
    print(col_dir)
    with open(os.path.abspath("Instagram/Data/quotes.json")) as f:
      data = json.load(f)

    def getQuote():
        quote = random.choice(data)
        return ('"'+quote['text']+'" - '+quote['author']+" \n\n Follow us for more! \n \n #photography #travelphotography #naturephotography #streetphotography #foodphotography #portraitphotography #photographylovers #landscapephotography #weddingphotography #blackandwhitephotography #filmphotography #canonphotography #fashionphotography #mobilephotography #photographyislife #nikonphotography #photographyeveryday #photographylover #photographysouls #architecturephotography #photographyislifee #wildlifephotography #nightphotography #iphonephotography #macrophotography #urbanphotography #bnwphotography #analogphotography #dogphotography #photographylife")
    print(getQuote())
    bot = Bot() 
    bot.login(username = "",  password = "")
    def upload(path): 
        bot.upload_photo(path, caption="Follow for more!")
        toast.show_toast("Notification",str(num)+" images are uploaded",duration=300,threaded=True)
        print(str(num)+" images are uploaded")
        print("----------------------------------")
        try:
            os.remove(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), path+""))
        except:
            os.remove(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), path+".REMOVE_ME"))
    while True:
        GetImage()
        col = glob(col_dir)
        ranTime=random.randrange(1800,3600)
        print("Images in stack: "+str(col))
        print("Waiting 30 to 60 minutes. Resuming at "+str(time.ctime(time.time() + ranTime)))
        #time.sleep(ranTime)
        print("Upload sequence has begun...")
        lbl.configure(text=num)
        window.update()
        if num % 50 == 0:
            sendMessage(str(num)+" images uploaded.")
        for i in col:
            num+=1
            lbl.configure(text=num)
            window.update()
            ChangeNum(num)
            upload(i)
            imageDir = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
            for item in imageDir:
                if item.endswith(".REMOVE_ME"):
                    os.remove(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), item))
```

Here is an image of my file structure
[image: File structure main folder]
[image: Files in Data.txt]

How to make the bot start uploading the images with captions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, it's important to know the limits on Instagram captions! The maximum caption length is 2,200 characters (which is pretty darn long!). You can also use up to 30 hashtags. So just satisfy 2 criteria's:

1. Caption length should be less than 2200 characters
2. Caption should have less than 30 hashtags